# How can 2 players play coop on Nintendo Switch Lite with only 1 external pro controller?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch

I have a Nintendo Switch Lite and a USB pro controller. I want to play coop, with one player using the built in controls and another using the Pro controller plugged in through the USB port.

However, the switch seems to only recognize the controller as 1. It does not differentiate between the built in controls and the controller input.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need 2 external controllers to play using the same screen, the Lite can't use itself as a controller and an external controller at the same time.